# How can I lineup my text and my button in the following example?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My text is currently sitting below my button and I cannot get it centered despite playing around with margins and padding

http://jsfiddle.net/9b9at/

I would like them to be centered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick you text in a `<span>`, `float:` it and add some `line-height:`

http://jsfiddle.net/9b9at/2/